# Steam (Elementary OS 6.1)

Tags: steam

i can't install Steam in ElementaryOS 6.1, this is error message

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enable support for the 32-bit package because Steam client is only available as 32-bit app:

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Then update the APT cache:

`sudo apt update`

Now you should be able to install Steam without any trouble.